Why symfony 7 cant set PrePersist parametr?
I use doctrine and Symfony 7, trying to create User Entity and form for user registration.

Also i used PrePersist function to set date_create, but seems like it doesnt work:

I also tried Gedmo Doctrine extensions, but it didnt help too...

Do you have the #[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks] attribute declared on the class itself?

@iainn , you are right) i forgot to place it in my code.... I've lost 3 hours of my working time because of it.

To make callbacks work, there should be:
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
Section before class code.

